# 'URL No Longer Exists' error from inline Visualforce page within a Page Layout

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, package-install

Please check the below image attachment to see clearly what I am trying to say. I can check the VisualForce page 'Preview' and be able to see what I need. However, When I am trying to get that visualforce page right after installing package, I am getting 'URL No Longer Exists' error. I tried *Uncheck the boxes for Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers* and adding `<apex:page standardController="SObject" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false">` as suggested by SALESFORCE website with no luck. here is the VisualForce code that I am using. Please let me know If I need to add something else.

```
<apex:page controller="LinkToConfig" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Process to link Org with Salesforce">
            <apex:outputText >
                <table style="float: left" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <ul><li> A few steps to instruct after package installation. </li>
                </ul>
                </table>
            </apex:outputText><br></br>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!RemoteSite}" target="_blank" value="NEW REMOTE SITE" styleClass="btn" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px; padding: 4px; text-decoration: none;"> 
            </apex:commandLink><br></br>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!ConnApps}" target="_blank" value="CONNECTED APPS" styleClass="btn" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px; padding: 4px; text-decoration: none;"> 
            </apex:commandLink><br></br>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

And I mentioned direct links to "Connected apps" and "new remote site" settings like `new pagereference('/apex/xyz')` . 
Can Anyone suggest me what to do in this case to get VisualForce page? 
[image]

Comment: Did you include the namespace when trying to access the URL?

Comment: @Eric , I did not. Could you be more specific about URL that you are mentioning. I have created VF page and added that to CustomLink which we can add to PostInstall instructions while Creating package. I request you to please provide me a few more details how to add NameSpace to "URL" . Thanks in advance.

Comment: then the url in the link